# What is winsock error 10099

Tags: c++, winsock, multicast

I am trying to subscribe to a multicast group in C++. The likely address 238.0.0.1
Code has been in production for over a year

```
struct ip_mreq mreq;
unsigned long mcastAddr = (238 << 24) | 0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 1;
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = htonl(mcastAddr);

if (setsockopt(m_fdIn, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
{
   WARNF("multicast subscription failed, winsock error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
   return -1;
}
```

but I just got a report from the field

> multicast subscription failed, winsock error 10099

When I look up the code on msdn I dont see the code listed
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What could go wrong on the host machine that would generate this particular error?
What do we tell them to change to fix it?
As I said code has been deployed for a while so I am assuming its a local config issue with multicast.

Comment: Instead of manually shifting bits, use `inet_addr("238.0.0.1")` instead. In any case, there is no error 10099 defined, unless it is new and not documented yet. `setsockopt()` is not documented to report a 10099 error. The closest values defined in the Winsock SDK are `WSANOTINITIALISED` (10093) and `WSAEDISCON` (10101).

Comment: I would guess that multicast is disabled on the host in question.